# Telegram Bot не могу отправить ссылку

Tags: php, html5, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для телеграм через `webhook` на проекте под `yii2`, установил плагин `aki/yii2-bot-telegram`.
Простой текст нормально отправляется, а вот со ссылкой происходит проблема. Ссылку формирую вот так:

```
$text .= 'Ссылка на диалог: <a href="' . Yii::$app->params['baseUrl'] . '/#/dialogs/' . $dialog['id'] . '">' . Yii::$app->params['baseUrl'] . '/#/dialogs/' . $dialog['id'] . '</a>' . "\n";
$text .= 'Или отправьте ответ на это сообщение для ответа пользователю.';
```

А отправку делаю так:

```
Yii::$app->telegram->sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'text' => $text,
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
    'disable_web_page_preview' => true
]);
```

Также пробывал отправку в `Markdown`, естественно с формированием, который он просит для ссылки. Результат один и тот же - приходит обычный текст. Как поправить?

Comment: А ошибку можно?) И еще, можно узнать что в baseUrl и id?

Comment: @kotleni Ошибку нельзя потому, что ошибки нет.
Просто мне надо, что отправлялась ссылка, а она формируется как ссылка, а приходит как текст, т.е. выглядит так как и должна при форматировании html, но кликнуть на неё нельзя.

Comment: Проверьте baseUrl на валидность ссылки.

Comment: @kotleni Вот только может ли быть такая ссылка вообще быть валидной `http://localhost:4200/#/dialogs/37`
ну зайти я на неё покрайне мере могу

Comment: попытайся отправить просто ссылку

Comment: @kotleni Да я эту ссылку прост отправляю и она приходит как текст, а все другие прихоядт норм, стало быть telegram там тестит ссылки которые через него кидают или что-то в этом роде

Comment: а ты прав; Telegram ужасен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое - вместо **localhost** используй **127.0.0.1**;
Telegram не понимает ссылок без точки в доменном имени.